Cloth simulation going insane when character starts moving

The simulation is fine at first, but when the arms start moving:

it happens even when I up the quality. Maybe the cloth is somehow influenced by the bones?
And also I do need the 0.03 outer thickness.
blend file

Your link asks for an authorization. But do you have parented the cloth to the armature?

@moonboots, no, I have it separately

https://file.io/UP2ZTs1I8yUO

it doesn't work either   :/

That second links says that the file has been deleted! Assuming your Blend file is smaller than 30 meg, you you can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

no, file is 45mb and 36 when archived.
here's another link, I can't put it into my post, because it's temporal
https://dropmefiles.com/XMEx2

I don't know how to download from your last link, could you please use another platform like workupload or wetransfer?

@moonboots https://workupload.com/file/CRcujt4MuWT

it looks like the Decimate of the body causes the problem, but anyway, you can't count on the Cloth simulation only to simulate the cloth, it needs to be parented to the armature, and give it a Pin group where it is supposed to be stiff

@moonboots Thank you for the answer, it turns out that the modifier was the actual issue. I thought that it would reduce bake time. Why don;t you add this as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted, I guess you can get some reputation for it

It looks like the Decimate of the body causes the problem, probably because it creates bad topology, so disable it.
Also, you can't count on the Cloth simulation only to simulate the cloth, it needs to be parented to the armature, and give it a Pin group where it is supposed to be stiff.
